# How do I Use C # Query MYSQL data And displays?

Tags: c#, mysql

I try to follow the teaching, but still fails

I tried to use this code to query `NAME` but did not succeed in show

My database: `testdb` table: `playdata`

I want to use the primary key 'SID' to get NAME

I think `SL1` should display `TEST NAME`, but nothing show

Or am I doing wrong?

I found the insert information in other teaching, his success

But the query fails

```
string connStr = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=123123;database=testdb;";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
try
{
    conn.Open();
    String cmdText = "SELECT NAME * FROM playdata WHERE SID = 001";
    command = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
    String _name = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    SL1.Text = _name;
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    switch (ex.Number)
    {
        case 0:
            SL1.Text = "Can not connect";
            break;
        case 1045:
            SL1.Text = "Input error";
            break;
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
conn.Close();
```

----*edit
----Efficient coding

```
    string connStr = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=123123;database=testdb;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

    String cmdText = "SELECT NAME FROM playdata WHERE SID = 'S01'";
    command = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
    conn.Open();
    try {
        string str = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        SL1.Text = str;
    } catch {
        SL1.Text = "error";
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `SID` column?

Comment: Error seems to be because the string instead of int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in your query, you've forgot to remove `*` sign. Your code should be like this:

```
String cmdText = "SELECT NAME FROM playdata WHERE SID = 001";
```

And, may be, you should add `''` for your `SID` filter, as it can be not a integer:

```
String cmdText = "SELECT NAME FROM playdata WHERE SID = '001'";
```

Comment: It worked thank :D! 
By the way, I also tried to use the same code in ASP.NET, but it does not seem to work ，What could be the reason?

Comment: I have no idea, no error message, but the web bottom write "waiting for localhost ...", then there is no change SL1, even the same code

Comment: In your connection string you are trying to connect the `127.0.0.1` (localmachine), and, if you have the database not on the server you have ASP.NET, it will never connect. You have to change connection string to pass a database server IP

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, you mean change 'connStr' string?
How should enter?

Comment: You should replace `127.0.0.1` with actual server name in `connStr`